# Nginx+Apache環境でPerlスクリプトが動作するようにする方法

Tags: apache, nginx, perl

お世話になります。
Nginxをリバースプロキシとして、Apacheを動作させようとしています。
とりあえず、大体の設定作業は終わり、HTMLとPHPは正常に表示できるようになりました。
そして、現在Perlスクリプトを動かそうとしているのですが、やり方がよくわからずにいます。
とりあえず、Apacheのバーチャルホストの設定ファイルに下記を記述しました。

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</IfModule>
```

しかし、これではまだ不十分なのか、Perlのソースがブラウザ上に直接表示されてしまいます
Nginx側で何か設定が必要なのでしょうか。
また、設定が必要な場合、どのような設定をすればよいでしょうか。
環境は、Ubuntu18.04.3、Nginx Ver.1.16.1、Apache Ver.2.4.29です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念のため、Apacheの設定変更後にプロセスの再起動はしましたか？

Comment: はい。「sudo systemctl restart apache2 nginx」でApacheとNginxを両方とも再起動しています。

Comment: Apacheの設定がおかしいと思います。https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/howto/cgi.html などを参照して、設定してみてください。

Comment: お世話になります。回答欄に記載しましたが、モジュールがロードされていなかっただけのようです。アドバイスありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

お世話になります。
私の単純なミスで、cgiを動作させるモジュールがロードされていなかったため、Perlスクリプトが動かなかったようです。

```
a2enmod cgi
```

でモジュールを有効化して、Apacheを再起動させたところ、正常に動作するようになりました。
ありがとうございました。
以上、今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。